# MediaCodec and ImageReader

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I would like to access the YUV images of a video, and passing a ImageReader surface to a MediaCodec [(as refered in the documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) looked like a really smart way to do it. However, i can't make sense of the data inside the Image instance supplied by the onImageAvailable callback. Just looking at its Y plane, it looks to be mostly 0 values, no matter what is the video i provide.
I read some @fadden comments that looked a bit old by now, referring that the ImageReader surface was not available yet for MediaCodec, is this still the case? Did anyone succeeded in implementing a MediaCodec decoding to a ImageReader surface solution?

To illustrate, i was hopping for the Y plane to be like this:

[image: Good Y Plane]

and it comes out as:

[image: Bad Y Plane]

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but maybe this api will help:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#getOutputImage(int)

Comment: Thanks, it did not solved the issue, but it was a good work-around!

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. In my case, it is because I did not specicify the MediaCodec to output the same format image as the ImageReader.

```
        int imageFormat = ImageFormat.YUV_420_888;

        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                videoFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH),
                videoFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT),
                imageFormat,
                3
        );
        // I add the following line of code.
        videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible);
        // Then initialize the MediaCodec with videoFormat.
```